# Ethers.js Error: invalid json response with provider.getEtherPrice() function

Tags: angular, typescript, etherscan

I´m trying to obtain the Ether Price using ether.js. 
I tried to do call the function

```
const etherProvider = new ethers.providers.EtherscanProvider('homestead', 'ETHERSCANAPIKEY');
etherProvider.getEtherPrice().then(data => {
   console.log(data);
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

And gives me this err:

Error: invalid json response
    at XMLHttpRequest.o.onreadystatechange [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYreadystatechange] (ethers.min.js:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (zone-evergreen.js:1191)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:465)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone-evergreen.js:1629)

I also tried to call directly the api of etherscan:

```
this.http.get('https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=stats&action=ethprice&apikey=APIKEY')
.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

And its returning `null`

Typescript 3.7.5
Angular 8.3.23
Node 12.16.1
Ionic 5.4.15

Comment: Have you set your API key? Can you extract the HTTP request and response contents for the API call using the Network tab of your web browser console?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Yes, i set my API Key. If I insert the url in the browser it returns the response that i want, but if I do a Request from the browser console, returns null

Comment: I think this is what happens: It returns null, because it is a Promise (or callback).  You need to put the data processing logic inside the function you pass to `subscribe()`. This is because you cannot process the data until the asynchronous IO gets you the data.